# how to send reference in mex matlab to C++ code

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

If my function in C has the input `mystruct &input`, how should I send it in MATLAB `coder.ceval`?
I've tried to use `coder.ref`, `coder.wref` but  I get error C2664 while compiling the MEX function.
The error I get is

> cannot convert from 'mystruct *' to 'mystruct &'

the code-

In Matlab -

codet.cstructname(struct_mat,"mystruct",extern,'HeaderFile','MyStruct.h')
coder.ceval('func',coder.ref(struct_mat))

In C++ -

void func(mystruct &struct_var)

Comment: C doesn’t have references, your function is C++.

Comment: But are you telling MATLAB that this is a C function? `coder.ref` should be correct in a C++ context. Please show (a minimal version of) your code.

Comment: I added the code